# Programatically adding All Authenticated Users

Tags: authentication, object-model

I want to give all authenticated users read access to a list (that stores some configuration for a feature).

"All Authenticated Users" is a special concept in SharePoint, but the implementation varies based on authentication type - is there a universal way to retrieve that principal, regardless of authentication type?

I know for windows authentication, I can get the user via `web.EnsureUser("NT Authority\authenticated users")`, and in Claims I can use `web.EnsureUser("c:0(.s|true")` (or All Authenticated Users instead of the claim string), but I'd like to avoid hard coding that..

I also suspect that "NT Authority\authenticated users" won't work on a non-English OS - does anyone know if that is the case?